# Building war file with -Pprod does not set active spring profile to prod when running war file

Tags: jhipster

I am attempting to build a jhipster application for production with the following command:
./mvnw -Pprod package

According to the documentation here https://jhipster.github.io/profiles/ the war file should automatically run with the active spring profile "prod" when it is kicked off. However, I'm finding that is runs with the defaults of swagger,dev.

Am I missing something here? If I set --spring.profiles.active=prod when running the build war file the correct profile is activated but according to the documentation, prod should be activated by default based on the way I built it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're right, it's supposed to work as you describe. Did you have any error while building the WAR?

Comment: The maven build completes successfully. There are a couple of yarn warnings but maven-war-plugin:2.6:war and spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE.repackage complete successfully.